# Using Applescript to Search PDFs with Safari

Tags: pdf, safari, applescript

I have about 1000 URLs that link to remote PDF files that I need to determine which are searchable by Safari and which are not. I have my script looping and opening the URLs in Safari but I am stuck on the last 2 steps below.

Can someone help? Thanks

The script needs to:

For each URL:

Tell Safari to

1. Open a given URL (in this case a remote PDF)
2. Search the PDF for the character "a" Using the find that pops up on a right-click, not Apple F
   [image]
3. Write the search result to a file

   ```
     set urlList to {"http://pricelist.list.com/pricelists/A/AEA_11-15-12.pdf", "http://pricelist.list.com/pricelists/A/API_1608_04-05-13.pdf", "http://pricelist.list.com/pricelists/A/Access_02-01-12.pdf", "http://pricelist.list.com/pricelists/A/Allparts_Retail_01-01-11.pdf"}
      set numURLs to (count urlList)
      repeat with i from 1 to (numURLs)

   set theURL to (item i of urlList)
   tell application "Safari"
       open location theURL
       activate
       --Perform search
       --Write results to file
   end tell
   tell application "System Events"
       tell process "Safari"
           click menu item "Close Other Tabs" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
       end tell
   end tell
   delay 5
   ```

   end repeat

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to download the PDFs and use shell scripting:

```
brew install poppler wget parallel
cat ~/Documents/urls.txt | parallel -P8 wget
for f in *.pdf; do [[ $(pdffonts -- "$f" 2> /dev/null | wc -l) -eq 2 ]] && printf %s\\n "$f"; done
```

pdffonts prints two lines of output for scanned PDFs that don't have embedded fonts. See [How do I determine programmatically if a PDF is searchable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820241/how-do-i-determine-programmatically-if-a-pdf-is-searchable).